# How to solve Service: Endpoint not found error on launching default IIS page

Tags: windows, iis

I am getting following error message on viewing default iis page. How to resolve this issue.

[image]

System Details
OS Version:Win 10 - 1607 (14393.187)

IIS Version: 10.0.14393.0

[image: Enabled Feature details]

Comment: You are accessing the default page of a site who monitors `http://localhost`, and this site returns the error page (not IIS itself). So when it complains that way, you need to dig into the source code of that site so as to find an answer. Nobody here can help as no access to the code is provided.

Comment: So could you see this request in your IIS log? And did you place any service application in your Default website? If so, you need to check your web app configuration. If you didn't place anything in inetpub, then you could try the solution in this link.https://forums.iis.net/t/1237727.aspx?IIS10+0+14393+0+Service+Endpoint+Not+Found

Comment: @JokiesDing: I have tried the steps in that link, it did not work out, I did not place any service application. Recently I have formatted my machine and I am enabling IIS for the first time

Answer (score 0):

After replacing applicationHost.config from old history(C:\inetpub\history) the issue got resolved